# How to access Objects values outside a method in android parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have here a method `methodOne` which saves an object to the cloud:

```
    ParseObject obj;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Parse.initialize(this, APP_ID, CLIENT_KEY);
    }

    public void methodOne(View v){
            obj = new ParseObject("PersonName");
            obj.put("fname", t1.getText().toString());
            obj.saveInBackground();
    }
```

How can I access the `obj` object of the class ParseObject outside the method?

Comment: I am not getting issue. Its global variable as per code you have shown.. isn't it?

Comment: yep. but how about when I have another method that saves another object to the same class? Say for instance another name of a person? Should I instantiate again the `obj` to `new ParseObject("PersonName")` ?

Comment: obj is a global object and you can access it anywhere. Inside or outside of any method.

Comment: Yes you have to create new object for that.

Comment: @sureshkumar, that's right. But the instantiation is done within the `methodOne`. How about inserting another name using another method?

Comment: You have to declare it locally with in the method.

Comment: @MysticMagic Is there any way that I should instantiate an object of the class only once? So that if I have hundreds of methods, I do not have to have a `new` keyword on each method?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void methodOne(View v){
            ParseObject obj = new ParseObject("PersonName");
            obj.put("fname", t1.getText().toString());
            obj.saveInBackground();
    }
```

Comment: A code dump is *never* a good answer. At least explain why you think this solves the problem stated...